# Cannot verify Rails installion on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am trying to follow the Setup Ruby On Rails instructions on the rails website in order to install Rails

https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra

However when I get to the step

rails -v

I keep getting this error

```
rails -v
Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)
Rails 4.2.6
```

I've tried uninstalling rails and installing the previous version 4.1.15 but I get the same error.. I've tried looking at other forums but I cannot seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You still have Rails installed (version 4.2.6). The second line you get is an error that comes from a change in the latest version of Thor. You can read more about it here: https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0192-release-2016-11-26